# RxSwift with MVVM, RadioButton not working

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button, rx-swift

im stucked with this situation

This is the view
raidobuttons and label are inside of a stackview

```
    var radioButton: RadioButton = RadioButton(duration: 0).usingAutoLayout()
    var radioButtonNo: RadioButton = RadioButton(duration: 0).usingAutoLayout()
    let lblYes: UILabel = UILabel().usingAutoLayout()
    let lblNo: UILabel = UILabel().usingAutoLayout()
```

The model im working with input and output, but i don´t know if i should set the control on viewmodel or in controller

and whats the sequence?

Model:

```
   struct Input {
        let trigger: Driver<Void>
        let viewWillAppear: Driver<Void>
        let callingCodeTap: Driver<Void>
        let yesTap: Driver<Void>
        let phoneNumber: Driver<String>
        let callingCodeDidBeginEditing: Driver<Void>
        let phoneNumberDidEndEditing: Driver<Void>
        let actionBtnTap: Driver<Void>
    }

    struct Output {
        let triggered: Driver<Void>
        let viewWillAppear: Driver<Void>
        let callingCodeTapped: Driver<Country>
        let yesTapped: Driver<Void>
        let country: Driver<Country>
        let phoneNumber: Driver<(Bool, Phone)?>
        let callingCodeDidBeginEditing: Driver<Void>
        let phoneNumberDidEndEditing: Driver<Void>
        let actionBtnTapped: Driver<Void>
        let error: Driver<IBANError>
    }
```

And finally the controler

```
         output
        .yesTapped
        .do(onNext: { print("test")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the code in your controller the most probable reason why the closure in the `.do` operator is no called is that there is no subscription created for this observable. `.do` is just an operator just like `.map` etc.. You need the "end" in your sequence (observers produces values for subscribers) in this case you are missing the subscriber.

You have 2 options to solve your problem:

#### Add subscription and stay with "do" operator

```
         output
        .yesTapped
        .do(onNext: { print("test")})
        .subscribe()
```

#### Handle the values directly in subscription closures

```
         output
        .yesTapped
        .subscribe(onNext: { print("test") })
```

**Remember to keep the subscription alive as long as you need it**

For example you could use `DisposeBag` for that.

To do that you need an instance of `DisposeBag` in the place that will keep the lifecycle of the subscription. In your case `controller` might be the right place.

Simply create new property in your controller's class scope

```
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

and add `.disposed(by: disposeBag)` after the `.subscribe( ... )` method and your subscription will be alive as long as the controller is alive.

The final result would be

```
         output
        .yesTapped
        .subscribe(onNext: { print("test") })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```